# The updated convex hull algorithms in 2023?

Tags: linear-programming, convex-hull

I'm studying the convex hull algorithms in the high dimensions. There were two papers by [Bernard Chazelle](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Echazelle/pubs/ConvexHullAlgorithm.pdf) and [T.M. Chan](https://file:///D:/Local/Downloads/BF02712874.pdf) from the 90s, to have achieved the at then the state of the art complexity. However, when I tried to find the recent papers, most of ones I found was about the "approximation" of the convex hull, rather than finding the convex hull accurately.(Within the roundness)

Is there any updated high dimension algorithms that surpassed the ones from Bernard Chazelle and T.M. Chan's papers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm by Chazelle in the linked paper, for general dimension, is optimal in terms of worst case asymptotic complexity. So in terms of theoretical results for finding exact solutions, this paper is pretty much the last word. Indeed, Raimund Seidel notes in the chapter on convex hulls from the *Handbook of Computational Geometry* (Third edition, 2018) that

> ...in the sense of asymptotic worst case complexity the convex hull problem has been solved completely...

although he also notes the algorithm from Chazelle is not practical. I recommend reading the chapter to get an idea of the variants of the problem (mostly in terms of the description of the convex hull, which is more important in higher dimensions) and the theoretical status.

Comment: Footnotes: in Handbook of Computational Geometry (Third edition, 2018) Section 26 mentioned D. Avis and K. Fukuda's 1992 paper (A Pivoting Algorithm for Convex Hulls and Vertex Enumeration of Arrangements and Polyhedra)  to be the most plausible solution.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. Is it possible to surpass the complexity in this case? I need to basically find the convex hull of some continuous function `f_i(x)` in d dimension(which generated a point set P of thousands of points) to check the containment of a vector(without using the semi definite programming). I have went through several books, papers, and YouTube lectures, but still got little clue over this one.