# From the boundary description to the lattice description of the David Avis & Komei Fukuda's convex hull algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, convex-hull

This is a continued question from: [The updated convex hull algorithms in 2023?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/161887/the-updated-convex-hull-algorithms-in-2023)

From Handbook of Computational Geometry (Third edition, 2018) [section 26.3](http://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/chap26.pdf), Seidel mentioned the boundary and the lattice descriptions of the convex hull algorithms, and that the lattice description was less practical, where Avis-Fukuda's boundary description was more practical.

However, when I tried to read the [A pivoting algorithm for convex hulls and vertex enumeration of arrangements and polyhedra](https://%20https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02293050) by David Avis & Komei Fukuda, I'm not quite sure how the enumeration algorithm can be used to find the lattice description of the convex hull.

For me, the question was:

```
Given a set of points P in R^d
Check if a point x is inside the convex hull con(P) of the set P.
```

Thus, if might be easier to utilize the enumeration of the 2 dimensional faces to check the containment, or to check if adding the additional point x may or may not change the vertex enumeration?

But I'm a little bit confused of what the paper was doing.

Could you give a bit hint of how to translate the David Avis & Komei Fukuda's convex hull algorithm to check the lattice containment, please?